# Unicode filenames on Windows with Python & subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, windows, unicode

Why does the following occur:

```
>>> u'\u0308'.encode('mbcs')   #UMLAUT
'\xa8'
>>> u'\u041A'.encode('mbcs')   #CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER KA
'?'
>>>
```

I have a Python application accepting filenames from the operating system.  It works for some international users, but not others.

For example, this unicode filename:
u'\u041a\u0433\u044b\u044b\u0448\u0444\u0442'

will not encode with Windows 'mbcs' encoding (the one used by the filesystem, returned by sys.getfilesystemencoding()).  I get '???????', indicating the encoder fails on those characters.  But this makes no sense, since the filename came from the user to begin with.

Update:  Here's the background to my reasons behind this...
I have a file on my system with the name in Cyrillic. I want to call subprocess.Popen() with that file as an argument. Popen won't handle unicode. Normally I can get away with encoding the argument with the codec given by sys.getfilesystemencoding(). In this case it won't work

Comment: Please add information about the Popen call: what's the executable? is it written by you?

Comment: The executable is written by my team; we've resolved this issue by encoding the command-line in utf-8, and having the called executable decode it.  (as suggested by John Machin below.  Thanks!)

Comment: In order to get a valid answer please post a sample section of the problematic code (popen). In any case calling encode('mbcs') will not solve your problem. Anything that will use the current codepage is not going to be a valid solution.

Answer (score 8):

In Py3K - at least from Python 3.2 - `subprocess.Popen` and `sys.argv` work consistently with (default unicode) strings on Windows. `CreateProcessW` and `GetCommandLineW` are used obviously.

In Python - up to v2.7.2 at least - `subprocess.Popen` is buggy with Unicode arguments. It sticks to `CreateProcessA` (while `os.*` are consistent with Unicode). And `shlex.split` creates additional nonsense.

Pywin32's `win32process.CreateProcess` also doesn't auto-switch to the W version, nor is there a `win32process.CreateProcessW`. Same with `GetCommandLine`.
Thus `ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateProcessW...` needs to be used. 
The subprocess module perhaps should be fixed regarding this issue.

UTF8 on `argv[1:]` with private apps remains clumsy on a Unicode OS. Such tricks may be legal for 8-bit "Latin1" string OSes like Linux.

**UPDATE** vaab has created a patched version of `Popen` for Python 2.7 which fixes the issue.
See https://gist.github.com/vaab/2ad7051fc193167f15f85ef573e54eb9
Blog post with explanations: http://vaab.blog.kal.fr/2017/03/16/fixing-windows-python-2-7-unicode-issue-with-subprocesss-popen/

Comment: There is an open bug for this: http://bugs.python.org/issue1759845 They aren't going to fix it. The only solution is to move to Python 3.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: I see at least two workarounds based on this answer on Python 2.7 for `subprocess`' args with characters outside `mbcs` encoding: 1. call appropriate for your case `os.*` function that might  already support Unicode 2. call `CreateProcessW` directly with Unicode arguments

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I was referring to "The subprocess module perhaps should be fixed". If you want to use the official API, then Python 3 is the only solution. That said, do you have a working example how to replace `subprocess.Popen` with `CreateProcessW`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: no. I haven't tried to call `CreateProcessW` manually.

Comment: @AaronDigulla: I have released a fix that exploit @J.F.Sebastian 's suggestions by calling ``CreateProcessW(..)`` via ``ctypes`` for python 2.7 on windows. [check this](http://vaab.blog.kal.fr/2017/03/16/fixing-windows-python-2-7-unicode-issue-with-subprocesss-popen/)

Comment: @vaab How about posting an answer which we can upvote?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: done. I posted answer that can be upvoted, with hopefully a nice sum up of the situation, although I must say @ kxr has a very nice one already.

Answer (score 5):

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm the author of the fix mentionned in the following.

To support unicode command line on windows with python 2.7, you can use
[this patch](https://gist.github.com/vaab/2ad7051fc193167f15f85ef573e54eb9) to `subprocess.Popen(..)`

**The situation**

Python 2 support of unicode command line on windows is very poor.

Are severly bugged:

- issuing the unicode command line to the system from the caller side (via `subprocess.Popen(..)`),
- and reading the current command line unicode arguments from the callee side (via `sys.argv`),

It is acknowledged and [won't be fixed](http://bugs.python.org/issue19264) on Python 2. These are fixed in Python 3.

**Technical Reasons**

In Python 2, windows implementation of `subprocess.Popen(..)` and `sys.argv` use the non unicode ready windows systems call `CreateProcess(..)` (see python [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/PC/_subprocess.c#L464), and MSDN [doc of CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)) and does not use `GetCommandLineW(..)` for `sys.argv`.

In Python 3, windows implementation of `subprocess.Popen(..)` make use of the correct windows systems calls `CreateProcessW(..)` starting from `3.0` (see [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.0/PC/_subprocess.c#L424) in `3.0`) and `sys.argv` uses `GetCommandLineW(..)` starting from `3.3` (see [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.3/PC/launcher.c#L1304) in `3.3`).

**How is it fixed**

The given [patch](https://gist.github.com/vaab/2ad7051fc193167f15f85ef573e54eb9) will leverage `ctypes` module to call C windows
system `CreateProcessW(..)` directly. It proposes a new fixed `Popen` object by overriding private method `Popen._execute_child(..)` and private function `_subprocess.CreateProcess(..)` to setup and use `CreateProcessW(..)` from windows system lib in a way that mimics as much as possible how it is done in Python `3.6`.

**How to use it**

How to use the given patch is demonstrated with this [blog post explanation](http://vaab.blog.kal.fr/2017/03/16/fixing-windows-python-2-7-unicode-issue-with-subprocesss-popen/). It additionally shows how to read the current processes
`sys.argv` with [another fix](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/572200/).

Comment: +1: I haven't tested it but it looks like a workable solution (`from win_subprocess import Popen` as a drop-in replacement,
 to enable `Popen(u"unicode command", ...)` where [`win_subprocess.py`](https://gist.github.com/vaab/2ad7051fc193167f15f85ef573e54eb9#file-win_subprocess-py)_

Answer (score 3):

[Docs for sys.getfilesystemencoding()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) say that for Windows NT and later, file names are natively Unicode. If you have a valid unicode file name, why would you bother encoding it using mbcs?

[Docs for codecs module](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html?highlight=mbcs#standard-encodings) say that mbcs encodes using "ANSI code page" (which will differ depending on user's locale) so if the locale doesn't use Cyrillic characters, splat.

Edit: So your process is calling subprocess.Popen(). If your invoked process is under your control, the two processes ahould be able to agree to use UTF-8 as the Unicode Transport Format. Otherwise, you may need to ask on the pywin32 mailing list. In any case, edit your question to state the degree of control you have over the invoked process.

Comment: I have a file on my system with the name in Cyrillic.  I want to call subprocess.Popen()  with that file as an argument.  Popen won't handle unicode.  Normally I can get away with encoding the argument with the codec given by sys.getfilesystemencoding().  In this case it won't work.

Comment: @Norman: please edit your question to include the info about subprocess.Popen()

Answer (score 2):

If you need to pass the name of an existing file, then you might have a better chance of success by passing the 8.3 version of the Unicode filename.

You need to have the [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) package installed, then you can do:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.GetShortPathName(u"C:\\Program Files")
'C:\\PROGRA~1'
```

I believe these short filenames use only ASCII characters, and therefore you should be able to use them as arguments to a command line.

Should you need to specify also filenames to be created, you can create them with zero size in advance from Python using Unicode filenames, and pass the short name of the file as an argument.

UPDATE: user bogdan says correctly that 8.3 filename generation can be disabled (I had it disabled, too, when I had Windows XP on my laptop), so you can't rely on them. So, as another more far-fetched approach when working on NTFS volumes, one can [hard link](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file__CreateHardLink_meth.html) the Unicode filenames to plain ASCII ones; pass the ASCII filenames to an external command and delete them afterwards.

Comment: You should never try to use 8.3 filenames, please remember that these are optional and they can be missing. It's a common practice to disable NTFS shortfilename generation in order to speedup filesystem.

Comment: If I may object to your first subsentence: one can *try* using 8.3 filenames, but should *not rely* on them. Ergo my "you might have a better chance".

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3, just don't encode the string. Windows filenames are natively Unicode, and all strings in Python 3 are Unicode, and Popen uses the Unicode version of the `CreateProcess` Windows API function.

With Python 2.7, the easiest solution is to use the third-party module https://pypi.org/project/subprocessww/. There is no "built-in" solution to get full Unicode support (independent of system locale), and the maintainers of Python 2.7 consider this a feature request rather than a bugfix, so this is not going to change.

For a detailed technical explanation of why things are as they are, please see the other answers.