# How to read file contents into a variable in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

This batch file releases a build from TEST to LIVE. I want to add a check constraint in this file that ensures there is an accomanying release document in a specific folder.

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\robocopy.exe" "\\testserver\testapp$"        
"\\liveserver\liveapp$" *.* /E /XA:H /PURGE /XO /XD ".svn" /NDL /NC /NS /NP
del "\\liveserver\liveapp$\web.config"
ren "\\liveserver\liveapp$\web.live.config" web.config
```

So I have a couple of questions about how to achieve this...

1. There is a `version.txt` file in the `\\testserver\testapp$` folder, and the only contents of this file is the build number (for example, 45 - for build 45)
   How do I read the contents of the `version.txt` file into a variable in the batch file?
2. How do I check if a file ,`\\fileserver\myapp\releasedocs\ {build}.doc`, exists using the variable from part 1 in place of {build}?

Answer (score 406, accepted):

Read file contents into a variable:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (version.txt) do set Build=%%x
```

or

```
set /p Build=<version.txt
```

Both will act the same with only a single line in the file, for more lines the `for` variant will put the *last* line into the variable, while `set /p` will use the *first.*

Using the variable – just like any other environment variable – it is one, after all:

```
%Build%
```

So to check for existence:

```
if exist \\fileserver\myapp\releasedocs\%Build%.doc ...
```

Although it may well be that no UNC paths are allowed there. Can't test this right now but keep this in mind. Note that with the set /P command the file cannot be in Unicode format.

Comment: The `set` method only reads about 1024 characters, why is that?

Comment: Probably due to limits of a buffer within `cmd`. It's a horrible language for reliable scripts.

Comment: I know, I struggled for hours to replace a string in a file :|

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, `set /p` calls `cmd!ReadBufFromInput` with a stack allocated buffer to read 1023 wide characters (2046 bytes). It reads 1023 bytes from the file, assuming 1 byte per OEM/ANSI character, but it decodes the file using the current codepage, which isn't necessarily OEM/ANSI. Worst case is codepage 65001 and a file filled with 4-byte UTF-8 characters (e.g. an ancient script). You'll get 255 characters, plus a partially decoded character stored as the replacement character, U+FFFD.

Comment: On Windows 10 using the `for` variant gave me the first line of the file as well.

Comment: If you want to use a path with spaces for version.txt only second method will work: set /p Build=<"c:\temp\a dir with spaces\version.txt"

Comment: @Jan: `for /f "usebackq" %%x in ("path with spaces.txt") ...`. `help for` mentions this, by the way.

Comment: Can't tell if this works because it results in the `Echo is off` error when trying to output the variable, and using the workaround for _that_ error just prints an empty string.

Comment: Dissident Rage: You're probably having another error somewhere in there, or the file you're reading from is empty.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: You're having trouble with variable expansion, not with `set /p` not working.

Comment: Both methods fail for arbitrary Unicode characters. So, for example, if you are using a BAT file to work around https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910275/2279059, this will not work.

Comment: Both methods will read the contents of the file as it was when the script was *last* called, not the current content. It's not even the same as what `type version.txt` prints *directly before this*.

Answer (score 72):

You can read multiple variables from file like this:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (param.txt) do set %%G=%%H
```

where param.txt:

```
PARAM1=value1
PARAM2=value2
...
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution. 

to literally answer the OP, `(param.txt)` should be `(version.txt)` and it should contain `Build=45`

Comment: This is **the** solution.

Comment: %%G was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @John: for use directly on command line, replace every `%%G` with `%G`

Comment: I had to specify the absolute path to the file `for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%G in (%cd%\version.txt) do set %%G=%%H
`

Answer (score 44):

just do:

```
type version.txt
```

and it will be displayed as if you typed:

```
set /p Build=<version.txt
echo %Build%
```

Comment: @jeb i know that but im still grateful for the type command because thats what i needed

Comment: Thank you for providing the type version. Works exactly for what I need, accessing file contents that are on a shared directory.

Answer (score 30):

To get all the lines of the file loaded into the variable, Delayed Expansion is needed, so do the following:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (version.txt) do set Build=!Build!%%x
```

There is a problem with some special characters, though especially `;`, `%` and `!`

Comment: Enclosing the entire `set` expression within double-quotes could avoid problems with at least _some_ special characters: `set "Build=!Build!%%x"`.

Comment: My script just prints "echo is ON".  Why is batch complete garbage?

Comment: Works for me without Delayed Expansion:

`set err=` (next line) `for /f "delims=" %%x in (err.tmp) do set "err=%err% %%x"`

Comment: _Why is batch complete garbage?_ ...for consistency?

Comment: @TrevorHickey Make sure that delayed expansion is on for the whole scope of where you are dealing with the variable that holds the file contents

Comment: @tivnet: Do you remember by chance what Windows version that (an empty `set err=` was working on? It does not work on my w10 (21H2).

Comment: @saulius2 - works on my w10

Comment: The accepted answer to this post wasted nearly one day of my life. This is the correct anwer.