# How to read a text file into an environment variable?

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

I have a one line text file (it will always be just one line). For example:

helloworld.txt contains *"hello world"*

I want to read this into an environment variable via the command prompt.

so `Set MyVar=somehow` reads *helloworld.txt*

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068929/how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file

Comment: [Windows cmd and MS-DOS are very different](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There's neither `for /f` nor `set /P` in DOS, and of course there can't be such a long name as `helloworld.txt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This only works because you want the last line (or a one-line file).

```
for /f "delims=" %f in (helloworld.txt) DO Set MyVar=%f
```

For more information, use

```
for /?
```

Comment: note that if you put this in a batch file use %% instead of %

Comment: this does not work for a sentence unfortunately, it only reads the first wrd

Comment: @foreyez, I changed the delimiter `for /f "delims=^" %f in (helloworld.txt) DO Set MyVar=%f`.  This wouldn't work if the string had a `^` in it, but you can pick whatever character you want.

Answer (score 10):

```
set /P VARNAME=<FILENAME.TXT
```

This will only work with first line and will handle everything up to the end of the line.

Found at http://ss64.com/nt/set.html