# CCRC Is it possible to send a comment on checkin which contains newlines in the check in message

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm trying to checkin a file using rcleartool and pass in a comment which contains more than 1 line (on windows)

```
> rcleartool.bat ci file1.cxx -c "comment 
with more than 
one
line"
```

but this doesn't seem to work well, infact I can't even enter such a think in bash or in cmd

can anyone give me any pointers if there is a way to encode \n in the message

doing

> rcleartool.bat ci file1.cxx -c "comment \nwith more than\none\nline"

simply leave the string "\n" in my message and not an actual newline

Is this possible? rcleartool doesn't seem to take the -cfile argument

Many thanks in advance Paul

Answer (score 1):

One immediate workaround is to use the `-cfile` parameter of [rcleartool ci](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkin.htm?lang=en)

That allows you to write your multi-lines comment in a file, and pass that file as a parameter to the checkin command.

If `-cfile` is not supported, then you need to wrap the checkin call in a script, as in "[Long commands split over multiple lines in Windows Vista batch (`.bat`) file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4455750/6309)"

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set text=This creates ^

a line feed
echo Test7: %text%
echo Test8: !text!
--- Output ---
Test7: This creates
Test8: This creates
a line feed
```

In that script, you can call `rcleartool i -m !Test8! afile` to see if that works.

Or you can [read the content of a file in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069068/6309), and use that variable as a `-m` parameter.

Comment: I was going to do that but unlike cleartool, rcleartool does not support -cfile from what I can tell  see  <br><pre>Usage: checkin | ci [-c/omment comment | -cq | -cqe | -nc] [-kee/p | -rm] [-pti/
me] [-fro/m source-pname] [-ide/ntical] {-cac/t | activity-selector ... | [-ato/
mic] pname ...}</pre>

Comment: @MyDeveloperDay OK, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @MyDeveloperDay By the way, don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (not for this question necessarily, but for all the other questions you already asked on Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 1):

I always hate answering my own questions, but it appears that you can put %0A instead of the \n in the checkin message and that then appears as a newline in the history

Comment: Answering one's own question is a good practice. And again, don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (for this question necessarily, but for all the other questions you already asked on Stack Overflow)