# Run echo and type without new line

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'm looking for a way to run echo and type in one line on DOS batch.

```
echo [No.1]
type No1.log
echo [No.2]
type No2.log
```

this script will output like below

```
[No.1]
No1.log No1.log No1.log No1.log
[No.2]
No2.log No2.log No2.log No2.log
```

But this is not good for legibility. I want to print like below

```
[No.1] No1.log No1.log No1.log No1.log
[No.2] No2.log No2.log No2.log No2.log
```

Comment: To print without new line there are already a question, please search and/or look at SO suggestions before asking. For type it depends on the content of the file, so if the file contains a new line obviously you can't type in a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reading the content of the log, then concatenating it?

For example, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068929/how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file) to read the log:

```
set /p log1=<No1.log
```

Then echo the line:

```
echo [No.1] %log1%
```