# Read file for parameter and value -> skip specific lines

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I found the code for my loop in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3069068/7109162). Now I modified to loop a bit to match my needs and now it looks like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (test-config.txt) do (
    call set "%%x"

echo %%x |findstr /b "SERVICE_NAME" >nul ||(

call set "def=%%def%% --"%%x""  
) || (
 echo 

)
)
```

the loop reads a file with following format:

```
par1=val1
par2=val2
par3=val3
```

and its working as needed. Now I want to add some comments in between the lines like this:

```
par1=val1
par2=val2
//value is not default
par3=val3
```

sadly the loop now tries to create a parameter with the comment as name and no value. Can you show me how I have to enhance my loop to ignore the comment lines? Please note that a value could also include `//`

Comment: Include the `=` sign in the search string of `findstr`, and implement another filter for `//`: `echo(%%x| > nul 2>&1 (findstr /V /B /C:"//" | findstr /B /C:"SERVICE_NAME=") || ( ... )` (remove the `2>&1` part to not suppress error messages)

Comment: @aschipfl thanks for your answer. i replaced `echo %%x |findstr /b "SERVICE_NAME" >nul ||` with your `echo(%%x| > nul 2>&1 (findstr /V /B /C:"//" | findstr /B /C:"SERVICE_NAME=") ||` but i still get the error `Environment variable// value is not default not defined`

Comment: `for /f "eol=/ delims=" %%x`?

Comment: @MCND could you please explain the code? i am not very common with batch scripts

Comment: Sorry, the `eol` clause in the `for` command defines a character that will be used as a *discard flag*. Lines starting with this character (after delimiter removal) are discarded

Comment: @MCND ahh that sounds very good. thanks for this solution. if you want, write it as answer and i'll accept it

Comment: One weakness of the `eol=/` clause is that it will also flag a line starting with a single slash as a comment, and it is limited to a single character so that can't be overriden easily.  Probably not an issue in this case, but you should be aware.

Comment: @StevenK.Mariner thanks for your information. you are right that it shouldn't be an issue since i don't plan on adding parameter starting with a slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by MC ND,

`for /f "eol=/ delims=" %%x` works just fine.

Explanation:

> The `eol` clause in the for command defines a character that will be
>   used as a `discard flag`. Lines starting with this character (after
>   delimiter removal) are discarded