# Add all contents of a file in a single variable in Batch

Tags: batch-file

Suppose I have a text file with following contents:

```
Hello
World
Abc
```

Now I want to read this in batch and copy them into a single variable. So my variable should contain:

```
var=Hello World Abc
```

What is possible work around for this?
If I am trying I am either getting the first word or the last line word.

Thanks

Comment: To read a file in a batch-file you need to use a `FOR /F` command.  You can then use the `SET` command to assign the variable from the `FOR` command to your `VAR` variable.

Comment: seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068929/how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file

Comment: @Bentaye Yeah I have seen that, but not getting solution for my issue

Comment: @Squashman, I have tried that one. This :
for /f "delims=" %%x in (group.txt) do set Build=%%x
echo %Build%
It is giving only last line in Build variable

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Please share your efforts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. I have appended `\n` to each line in the read file.  I'm not sure how you expect that behavior to actually work:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "filecontents="
for /f "delims=" %%x in (input.txt) do (
    set filecontents=!filecontents!%%x\n
    )
echo %filecontents%
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this. I modified a bit to :
set "filecontents="
for /f "delims=" %%x in (group.txt) do (
    set "filecontents=!filecontents!%%x "
    )
echo %filecontents%
And it worked!!
Thanks a ton

Comment: Cool. I should have noted your example output just ignored linebreaks and left out the `\n` in my code.  Glad you got it going.

Answer (score 0):

To read the contents of a file in a batch file you can use a `FOR /F` command. You then use the `SET` command to assign a value to a variable. Also, you will need to utilized delayed expansion to reassign the existing variable to the original variable. A leading space will get assigned so the echo command is using a substring to remove it.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%G IN (file.txt) do set "var=!var! %%G"
echo %var:~1%
```