# Setting the classpath to a string which is in a txt file

Tags: java, cmd, junit4

I am trying to run the JUnit Test program through the command line from Java application. In java file, I am using the following commands,

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug");
```

In the *exec* function, I am adding the following command to run the Junit,

```
java -cp cp.txt org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Testing
```

In place of cp.txt, I gave the classpath which is very long and this approach throws me the following error,

```
Cannot run program "java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

So I want to place the string in cp.txt and give it as classpath in the command.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
TIA

Comment: Just put classpath in command. Wont work with file.

Comment: Just put the CLASSPATH into the JAR file and use `java -jar` as you were originally doing.

Comment: @EJP what does that mean putting the classpath into the jar file, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @harry Have you ever heard about manifest file?

Comment: @Antoniossss yeah, I heard of it. Do u want me to add an entry in that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by just storing the content of your text file to a variable and then use this as your class path. If your using e.g. bash you can simple do that in a one-liner:

```
java -cp $(cat cp.txt) org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Testing
```

If your text file contains newline, you could even simply replace them with `;` like this:

```
java -cp $(cat cp.txt | tr '\n' ';') org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Testing
```

I'm pretty sure you can do this on Windows too, but there the syntax is probably slightly different. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068929/how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file) should help you there.

Comment: Even for a variable, there is a limit, so unable to store the entire classpath in the variable.