# Batch variable being set to ■1 instead of intended output

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm putting together a script and need to take a file's content as input for setting a variable. I'm using Out-File to produce a text file:

```
$string | Out-File -FilePath C:\Full\Path\To\file.txt -NoNewLine
```

Then I am using that file to set a variable in batch:

```
set /P variablename=<C:\Full\Path\To\file.txt
```

The content of that file is a unique id string that looks practically like this:

```
1i32l54bl5b2hlthtl098
```

When I echo this variable, I get this:

```
echo %variablename%
■1
```

When I have tried a different string in the input file, I see that what is being echoed is the ■ character and then the first character in the string. So, if my string was "apfvuu244ty0vh" then it would echo "■a" instead.

Why isn't the variable being set to the content of the file? I'm using the method from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068929/how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file) where the chosen answer says to use this syntax with the **set** command. Am I doing something wrong? Is there perhaps a problem with using a full path as input to a set variable?

Comment: I would assume the file is not saved as ASCII text.  It is most likely some form of unicode with a BOM.

Comment: Notepad++ tells me it is encoded as UCS-2 LE BOM. This file is being produced by Out-File in powershell, so I will explorer any options I have for encoding and report back.

Comment: Yes. You can tell [Powershell to output the file as ascii](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6).   Could we see the Powershell code please.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a bunch, I've added the powershell info (should've added to being with). Would you give an answer about the encoding so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Use `Out-File -Encoding oem` to produce files that `cmd.exe` reads correctly.

<sup>This effectively limits you to the 256 characters available in the legacy "ANSI" / OEM code pages, except `NUL` (`0x0`). See bottom section if you need full Unicode support.</sup>

---

In *Windows PowerShell* (but not PowerShell *Core*), **`Out-File` and its effective alias `>` default to [UTF-16LE character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16),** where most characters are represented as 2-byte sequences; for characters in the ASCII range, the 2nd byte of each sequence is `NUL` (`0x0`); additionally, such **files start with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) that indicates the type of encoding**.

By contrast, **`cmd.exe` expects input to use the legacy single-byte OEM encoding** (note that starting `cmd.exe` with `/U` only controls the encoding of its *output*).

When `cmd.exe` (unbeknownst to it) encounters UTF-16LE input:

- It interprets the bytes *individually* as characters (even though characters in UTF-16LE are composed of 2 bytes (typically), or, in rare cases, of 4 (a pair of 2-byte sequences)).
- It interprets the 2 bytes that make up the BOM (`0xff`, `0xfe`) *as part of the string*. With [OEM code page `437`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) (US-English) in effect, `0xff` renders like a *space*, whereas `0xfe` renders as `■`.
- Reading stops once the first `NUL` (`0x0` byte) is encountered, which happens with the 1st character from the ASCII range, which in your sample string is `1`.

Therefore, string `1i32l54bl5b2hlthtl098` encoded as UTF-16LE is read as  `■1`, as you state.

---

**If you need full Unicode support**, use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding:

- Use `Out-File -Encoding utf8` in PowerShell.
- Before reading the file in `cmd.exe` (in a batch file), run `chcp 65001` in order to switch to the [UTF-8 code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Intl/code-page-identifiers).

**Caveats:**

- Not all Unicode chars. may *render* correctly, depending on the font used in the console window.
- Legacy applications may malfunction with code page `65001` in effect, especially on older Windows versions.

  - A possible strategy to avoid problems is to *temporarily* switch to code page `65001`, as needed, and then switch back.

---

Note that the above only covers communication via *files*, and only in *one direction* (PowerShell -> cmd.exe).
**To also control the character encoding used for the *standard streams*** (stdin, stdout, stderr), both when sending strings to cmd.exe / external programs and when interpreting strings received from them, **see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375)** of mine.

Comment: Great and informative answer. I used Out-File -Encoding ASCII as suggested by Squashman in a comment, which worked for me but I'm sure I'll come back to this answer in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @OilyBusiness: Glad to hear it was helpful; `-Enocding ASCII` works fine, as long as you use only characters from the 7-bit ASCII range, but if you have accented characters (such as `ï`, for instance), they'll be replaced with _literal_ `?` - i.e., you'll lose information. `-Encoding oem` extends support to the code pages ("ANSI"/OEM) in effect based on the legacy system locale, so you'll get support for another 128 chars. (the 8-bit range), including some accented chars. Full Unicode support requires changing the code page, as stated.