# Assigning Output of Command to Variable not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
set thisVer="2"
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Deployments\deploy.ver" (
    FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`type "C:\Program Files\Deployments\deploy.ver"`) DO (
        type "C:\Program Files\Deployments\deploy.ver"
        set build=%%F
    )   
echo "Build version: %build%"
echo "This version: %thisVer%"
IF "%build%"=="%thisVer%" (
    echo "Same Versions"
    exit /B 0
)
```

The above code generates the following output...

```
"2"
"Build version:  Files\Deployments\deploy.ver"
"This version: "2""
```

Would someone please tell me why `%build%` is not equal to the contents of the file C:\Program Files\Deployments\deploy.ver?

Comment: [the Windows cmd is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386), there's no `for /f` command in DOS

Comment: The duplicate I posted is only one of your problems.  You are also missing a closing parentheses.  You should never assign quotes to your variables directly. The `IF` command is a literal string comparison, so you have two sets of quotes on one side of the comparison and only one set on the left side.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068929/how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file is where I grabbed the for /f from.... So I'm not sure why phuclv is referring to.

Comment: @G.Malsack, you tagged your question with the `DOS` tag.  You are not using `DOS`.  You are using Windows.  The `FOR /F` command was never a feature within `command.com` like it is with `cmd.exe`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-in-batch-not-behaving-as-expected - This resolved my problem. I added enabledelayedexpansion and replaced %build% with !build!

Comment: @G.Malsack, as I stated in my previous comments, Delayed Expansion was only one of your problems. The `IF` comparison will fail as well because you are assigning quotes to the `thisVer` variable.

Comment: AHHHHHHH, ok. sorry phuclv. Thank you for educating me on the difference between windows cmd and dos. Thank you Squashman for explaining that.

Comment: hmmmm, the IF comparison seems to be working just as is though, since the file contains the quotes as well.... 

New output: 
"Build version: "2""
"This version: "2""
"Same Versions"

Comment: @G.Malsack, ok that is fine but is not a best practice.  I wouldn't store the value with quotes in the file, but you can strip the quotes when you assign the value to the build variable. `set build=%%~F`

Comment: ok, I'll try to get that working as well. I really didn't like the quotes in the file anyway, however I was having issues with it prior to quoting the variable, so I just left it. Thanks for the heads up on this! :-)