# Encoding unicode path with filesystem encoding breaks it

Tags: python, unicode, mbcs

I do have the following path in the memory:

```
video_path = u'C:\\Documents and Settings\\user\\My Documents\\Downloads\\\xf5iv - Neon Phoenix [Free DL].mp3'
```

I'm trying to use it as a parameter in cmd, so I have to encode it.

```
video_path = video_path.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -i "%s" -vn -ac 2 -f mp3 audio.mp3' % video_path
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

However the string is not encoded in the right way - it converts the `\xf5` to `?` instead of `õ`. Therefore the file could not be found.

How can this happen? I'm using the default filesystem encoding (which is mbcs).

Comment: Windows uses Unicode paths.  Why are you encoding your Unicode string?

Comment: @André: It uses "Unicode", not Unicode.

Comment: I am speculating now, but what happens if you leave `video_path` as a unicode object (without encoding it), construct `cmd = u'..' % videopath` as a Unicode, too, and then encode at the end: `os.system(cmd.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()))`? On Linux and Python 2.7 it makes no difference, but it may be worth a try on your platform.

Comment: It's the same thing. The problem is that the 'mbcs' doesn't convert the `\xf5` char as it should, even though it is the default system encoding of windows XP (and probably 7 as well). It would seem like an implementation bug, but I'm not sure here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1910275/777186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910275/unicode-filenames-on-windows-with-python-subprocess-popen):

> In Py3K - at least from "Python" 3.2 - subprocess.Popen and sys.argv
>   work consistently with (default unicode) str's on Windows.
>   CreateProcessW and GetCommandLineW are used obviously.
>
> In Python - up to v2.7.2 at least - subprocess.Popen is buggy with
>   unicode arguments. It sticks to CreateProcessA (while os.* are
>   consistent with unicode). And shlex.split creates additional nonsense.
>   Pywin32's win32process.CreateProcess also doesn't auto-switch to the W
>   version, nor is there a win32process.CreateProcessW. Same with
>   GetCommandLine. Thus ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateProcessW... needs to
>   be used. The subprocess module perhaps should be fixed regarding this
>   issue.

Therefore, `subprocess.Popen` can't handle unicode right at Python 2.x versions.

My solution was renaming the input file to something random (with `os.rename`, which supports unicode), convert with `ffmpeg` that i launch with `subprocess.Popen`, and then rename it back.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode using UTF-8:

```
video_path = video_path.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Windows doesn't use UTF-8 in its filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am totally mistaken, the double backslash in

```
video_path = u'C:...\\xf5iv...'
```

causes the problem. There should be only one:

```
video_path = u'C:...\xf5iv...'
```

Otherwise the backslash is preserved as a backslash and left for `os.system()`, rather than `.encode()`, to deal with.

Comment: I don't know why stackoverflow shows it as two slashes - if you look at the code there are three backslashes. one escapes the first backslash, and the third escapes the unicode char.

Comment: @iTayb Interesting. But anyway, shouldn't _one_ backslash be sufficient?

Comment: @iTayb. Ah sorry. No. I get it now.

Comment: @iTayb I have taken the liberty of editing the question. It uses verbatim now instead of blockquote. At least the backslashes are correctly displayed now.