# Building an UCS4 string buffer in python 2.7 ctypes

Tags: windows, python-2.7, unicode, ctypes

In an attempt to recreate the `getenvironment(..)` C function of `_winapi.c` ([direct link](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/202fda55c2dffe27125703225e5af92254602dc6/Modules/_winapi.c#L754-L777)) in plain python using `ctypes`, **I'm wondering how the following C code could be translated**:

```
buffer = PyMem_NEW(Py_UCS4, totalsize);
if (! buffer) {
    PyErr_NoMemory();
    goto error;
}
p = buffer;
end = buffer + totalsize;

for (i = 0; i < envsize; i++) {
    PyObject* key = PyList_GET_ITEM(keys, i);
    PyObject* value = PyList_GET_ITEM(values, i);
    if (!PyUnicode_AsUCS4(key, p, end - p, 0))
        goto error;
    p += PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(key);
    *p++ = '=';
    if (!PyUnicode_AsUCS4(value, p, end - p, 0))
        goto error;
    p += PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH(value);
    *p++ = '\0';
}

/* add trailing null byte */
*p++ = '\0';
```

It seems that the function `ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(..)` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_unicode_buffer), [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1aa1803b3df2af9481628b8896babbd686d314ff/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#L294-L310)) is doing something quite close that I could reproduce if only I could have an access to `Py_UCS4` C type or be sure of its link to any other type accessible to python through `ctypes`.

Would `c_wchar` be a good candidate ?, but it seems I can't make that assumption, as python 2.7 could be compiled in `UCS-2` if I'm right ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28786554/458681)), and I guess windows is really waiting fo `UCS-4` there... even if it seems that `ctypes.wintypes.LPWSTR` is an alias to `c_wchart_p` in cPython 2.7 ([code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1aa1803b3df2af9481628b8896babbd686d314ff/Lib/ctypes/wintypes.py#L35)).

For this question, it is safe to make the assumption that the target platform is python 2.7 on Windows if that helps.

**Context** (if it has some importance):

I'm in the process of delving for the first time in `ctypes` to attempt a plain python fix at cPython 2.7's bug hitting windows `subprocess.Popen(..)` implementation. [This bug is a won't fix](https://bugs.python.org/issue19264). This bug prevents the usage of unicode in command line calls (as executable name or arguments). This is fixed in python 3, so I'm having a go at reverse implementing in plain python the actual cPython3 implementation of the required `CreateProcess(..)` in `_winapi.c` which calls in turn `getenvironment(..)`.
This possible workaround was mentionned in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113914/458681) to a question related to `subprocess.Popen(..)` unicode issues.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the part in the title about build specifically `UCS4` buffer. But it gives a partial answer to the question in bold and manage to create a unicode buffer that seems to work on my current python 2.7 on windows: (so maybe UCS4 is not required).

So we are here taking the assumption that `c_wchar` is what windows require (if it is UCS4 or UCS2 is not so clear to me yet, and it might have no importance, but I recon having a very light confidence in my knowledge here).

So here is the python code that reproduces the C code as requested in the question:

```
## creation of buffer of size totalsize
wenv = (c_wchar * totalsize)()    
wenv.value = (unicode("").join([
    unicode("%s=%s\0") % (key, value)
    for k, v in env.items()])) + "\0"
```

This `wenv` can then be fed to `CreateProcessW` and this seems to work.